# Are there any versions of Windows where the default permissions for the %LOCALAPPDATA% directory give access to other users?

Tags: windows, file-permissions

The application that I'm developing assumes that files that we create under a user's %LOCALAPPDATA% directory being accessible **only** by (1) that specific user, (2) adminstrators, and (3) LOCALSYSTEM.

I've recently been informed that this does not hold on all versions of Windows, and I'm having trouble verifying my assumption.  Does anyone know of a definitive source stating what the permissions of the %LOCALAPPDATA% directory should be for various versions of Windows?  Failing that, what is your experience?

Comment: I'm not aware of any version of Windows in which your assumption is false.  It would be very strange if there were.  Can't you ask the person in question to back up their rather surprising claim?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  They've conceded that they're probably wrong, so I'm going to keep assuming that %LOCALAPPDATA% is secure.